# IE Browser mode

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I know about the following tag to change the browser mode:

```
<META http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

I placed that tag directly under my `<HEAD>` tag.
You can see it in the following snippet:

```
<HEAD runat="server">
    <META http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

My issue is that when I load the page, the javascript widget does not work, probably because of the browser mode.

Here are my steps to get it to work manually:

I press F12 (developer tools opens) and then I press F5 (note that I haven't done anything in the developer tools window, I've only refreshed the page while the window is open).

Comment: "probably" because of the browser mode - how do you know? Are you getting any errors? What does the Javascript widget do?

Comment: the widget is a interactive gantt chart that runs on a intranet so sadly i cannot link it. im 100% sure its because of the browser mode. when it does not work and i open up the developer tools is in mode IE8 Compat View. then when i refresh the page and the developer tools has been opend nothing changes in therms of the browser mode

Answer (score 0):

If you forced the page into IE8 mode the console APIs like console.log will be missing as IE8 didn't ship them. When you open F12 the tool injects those APIs and then when you refresh the APIs are there and the page can call them.

So, most likely some code is calling something like console.log (without detecting for it) and throwing an exception. But that's just a guess.